# React : How can I append '%' sign after the number is entered?

Tags: reactjs

I want to append the % sign after the number is entered. How can I achieve this in React? I've concatenated the '%' sign but it is appearing after every number. How can I append it so that after entering the number e.g. 51 , the percent sign will appear?

### Here's the code:

```
 <InputBase
    className={`milestone-percent-rate`}
    autoComplete={"off"}
    placeholder={"20%"}
    maxLength="100"
    value={this.state.percent_rate + '%'}
    onChange={(e)=>{this.handleChange(e, "percent_rate")}}
/>
```

Comment: You will have to make sure you don't add it here `value={this.state.percent_rate + '%'}` cause when `onChange`  event is fired you are taking the entire value from the input box which later is getting stored in the state so try manipulating/concatenating it on `this.handleChange(e, "percent_rate")` method call level

Comment: you want some kind of mask effect. there are libs for that like https://github.com/sanniassin/react-input-mask

Answer (score 0):

you can write the append logic in the `handleChange` method like below .

```
this.setState({percent_rate,e.value+'%'})
```